# Tmux independent pane switching

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, tmux, console

I am wondering if it is possible to have a shared tmux session which has a window with multiple panes that the users can switch between independently. For example, user Alice should be able to have her cursor in pane 1 meanwhile user Bob has his cursor in pane 2. If both users are in the same pane, their input is multiplexed.

```
┌─────────┐
│  Alice  │
├─────────┤
│   Bob   │
└─────────┘
```

I am essentially asking how to display two sessions on the screen at the same time. If this is not possible to achieve with tmux, is there any other software I could use?

Edit:

I was able to make this work by combining GNU screen and tmux. First by creating a GNU screen with 2 splits on both Alice and Bob. Then I create a new-session in each of Alice's splits and attach them correspondingly in Bob's splits. This solution is not very good because it has 2 dependencies (GNU screen and tmux), is there any other solution?

Comment: If you have a solution that works, you should post it as an answer. If you think that it’s not very good, [edit] your question to say why.

Comment: This is answered (I think - not 100% sure it's exactly your use case) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/attach-to-different-windows-in-session